I18nContext Error "Object is possibly undefined for I18nContext.current().lang
I am implementing nestjs-i18n in NestJs and I have done all the setup as per this official document
But in service, I am facing the error "Object is possibly undefined"

Here are my full-service codes:
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { I18nContext, I18nService } from "nestjs-i18n";

@Injectable()
export class FeaturedAgentsService {
  constructor(private readonly i18n: I18nService) {}
  async test(): Promise<any> {
    const message = this.i18n.t("lang.HELLO", {
      lang: I18nContext.current().lang,
    });
    return { service: message };
  }
}


After the exploration, I solve this by issue.
The error Object is possibly 'undefined' arises because TypeScript is alerting to the potential of the I18nContext.current() function returning undefined. Accessing the lang property on an undefined value could lead to a runtime error.
To resolve this error, I use optional chaining (?.) to safely access the lang property of I18nContext.current() without causing runtime errors.
Here is the correct codes:
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { I18nContext, I18nService } from "nestjs-i18n";

@Injectable()
export class FeaturedAgentsService {
  constructor(private readonly i18n: I18nService) {}
  async test(): Promise<any> {
    const message = this.i18n.t("lang.HELLO", {
      lang: I18nContext.current()?.lang,  /***** Solved *****/
    });
    return { service: message };
  }
}


The error "Object is possibly undefined" typically occurs in TypeScript when there's a possibility of accessing properties or methods on an object that could be undefined. In your case, TypeScript is warning you that I18nContext.current().lang might be undefined.
To resolve this, you can add a check to ensure that I18nContext.current().lang is defined before accessing it. Here's how you can modify your code to handle this:
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { I18nContext, I18nService } from "nestjs-i18n";

@Injectable()
export class FeaturedAgentsService {
  constructor(private readonly i18n: I18nService) {}

  async test(): Promise<any> {
    // Check if I18nContext.current() is defined before accessing lang
    const lang = I18nContext.current()?.lang;

    // Assuming you want to use a default language if lang is undefined
    const message = this.i18n.t("lang.HELLO", { lang: lang || "en" });

    return { service: message };
  }
}

In this modified version, I18nContext.current()?.lang uses the optional chaining operator (?.), which returns undefined if I18nContext.current() is undefined. Then, we assign lang to this value. If lang is undefined, we fallback to a default language (in this case, "en"), but you can choose whichever default language is appropriate for your application.
